# Symfony Regex form validation

Tags: regex, forms, symfony

I have a form field that I want to match the following rules: at least 3 numbers then at least 7 a-z or A-Z letters, currently I have this but it does not work apparently because I get that my input is not valid even if I respect the rule I mentioned :

```
->add('NumberAcc', TextType::class, [
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank(),
                new Regex('/[0-9]{3,},[a-z]{7,}/')
            ],
        ])
```

Any ideas? (I know it wont work with Maj letters right now but it doesn't work either with lowercase letters

Comment: `012,abcdefg` matches. Is the comma in the middle a mistake or on purpose? Also, if you want to match uppercase letters too, include `A-Z` or make it case insensitive. (`/[0-9]{3,}[a-z]{7,}/i`)

Comment: Add your test case.

Comment: You cannot use `Regex` for that. My guess is you want `a1b2c3d4e5...` to be valid as well. Better use `Callback` constraint then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex contains a comma `,` between the numbers and the letters, which is not in the description of what you are trying to do. Also, if you want to capture both `a-z` and `A-Z` you have to explicitly specify it

```
/[0-9]{3,}[a-zA-Z]{7,}/
```

or make the regex case insensitive

```
/[0-9]{3,}[a-z]{7,}/i
```